# Add menu page on multisite

Tags: multisite, admin, admin-menu

I'm trying add menu page in multisite (settings will be global for all blogs).

Current code created in plugin and activated in network

```
function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        __( 'Custom Menu Title', 'textdomain' ),
        'custom menu',
        'manage_options',
        'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php',
        '');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page' );
```

But it show only in blog menu, I think should be different action hook, maybe someone can help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by "show only in blog menu"?

Comment: in multisite exist network menu and blogs menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [`network_admin_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/network_admin_menu/) hook.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
add_action('network_admin_menu', 'function_name');
function function_name() {
    add_menu_page( 
        "page_title", 
        "menu_title", 
        'capability', 
        'menu_slug', 
        'function_callback' 
    );  
}
```